# Prepare TestComplete project suite for submit

Tags: testcomplete8, source-control

I was wondering what is the best way to prepare a project (suite) for submit into version control. Since I am very happy with my way I wanted to share it. Maybe this helps someone. Criticism wanted. TestComplete must be closed before running this.

prepareForReconcileOfflineWork.bat

```
del /S *.bak
del /S *.tcLog
del /S *.tcLogs
del /S *.tcLS
del /S *.tcVis
del /S *.tlb
for /d /r . %%d in (doxygen_tmp,Log,testreview_tmp,Visualizer) do @if exist "%%d" rd /s /q "%%d"
```

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking?  Are you looking for feedback on your script or are you looking for suggestions relating to how to prep a project to check in?

Comment: I am looking for both but especially your second point. What do you do before checking in a project? Am I missing something?

Comment: Why not use the integrated source control?

Comment: Integrated source control does not support Perforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me what you are looking for is a policy suggestion regarding your check ins.  While I have not used TestComplete and Perforce my general rule of thumb is to check in what another user would need to build the project on their box.  So if there are required dependencies such as .dlls and such those should be checked in the project.  Settings files for the IDE or stuff like that may not be neccessary.  You can verify this works by getting the source to a different directory or even better another machine and trying to build it there.  I hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I use ignore list and here are what I added according to

- All the log files and folders
- *.~tc
- *.tcLS
- *.tcCfgExtender
- Visualizer folder and its files
- *.bak